# Proving the result of the limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I prove the this limit is 0 ? My experience says that the limit is zero because of the velocity that the denominator goes to zero, but I can't prove it with calculus.

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^xx^2}{x^{e^x}} = 0.$$

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{e^x} = \exp(e^x \cdot \ln x) = \exp(\exp(x) \cdot \ln(x)) \ge \exp(\exp(x))\qquad \forall x > e$$
And your terms are strictly positive. Therefor
$$0 \le \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2 \exp(x)}{\exp(\exp(x)\ln(x))} \le \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2 \exp(x)}{\exp(\exp(x))}$$
Proceed using l'Hospital and the squeeze theorem:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2 \exp(x)}{\exp\exp x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x^2+2x)\exp x}{\exp\exp x \cdot \exp x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2 + 2x}{\exp\exp x} = \ldots = 0$$
Now by the squeeze theorem, the original limit also equals $0$.